# The opposite of dissolve method

Tags: arcgis-pro, dissolve

Is there a method who break a shapefile into multiple files based on an attribute?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question in the body. The opposite of Dissolve is Union (or Intersect); the opposite of Split By Attributes is Append.

Answer (score 3):

[Split by attributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm):

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes.

Answer (score 1):

ArcToolbox .. Multipart to Single Part ..